# LEFT JOIN com WHERE em campo da primeira tabela OR campo da segunda tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, desempenho

```
SELECT COALESCE(tb2.numero_novo, tb1.numero_original) as numero
FROM
tb1
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id
WHERE 
tb1.numero_original = <PARAM> OR tb2.numero_novo = <PARAM>
```

A query acima gera um full table scan. Como otimizar esta query?

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb1   | index | numero_original| numero_original| 5       | NULL | 11683843 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb2   | ALL   | PRIMARY        | NULL           | NULL    | NULL |        2 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

O problema que preciso resolver é:
`tb1` é uma tabela que contém o campo `numero_original`. Quero criar a tabela `tb2` para armazenar um novo valor para este campo, (que chamei de `numero_novo`). Fiz isso pois não posso alterar o valor do campo `numero_original`, e não gostaria de criar o campo `numero_novo` na tabela `tb1`, pois ele seria NULL em mais de 95% da tabela de 11 milhões de registros.

**EDIT:**

Como falaram sobre índices, estou colocando mais informações:

- `tb1` possui como chave primária o campo `id`;
- O campo `numero_original` da tabela `tb1` possui índice;
- `tb2` possui como chave primária os campos `tb1_id` e `numero_novo`;
- A tabela `tb1` possui 11mi+ registros;
- A tabela recém-criada `tb2` possui 2 registros de testes.

.

```
mysql> show indexes from tb1;
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tb1   |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | id              | A         |    11066164 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tb1   |          1 | numero_original   |            1 | numero_original | A         |     5533082 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

mysql> show indexes from tb2;
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tb2   |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | tb1_id         | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tb2   |          0 | PRIMARY    |            2 | numero_novo    | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

EXPLAIN selecionando com WHERE somente na primeira tabela (`tb1`):

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb1   | ref  | numero_original| numero_original| 5       | const |    4 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb2   | ALL  | PRIMARY        | NULL           | NULL    | NULL  |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

EXPLAIN selecionando com WHERE somente na segunda tabela (`tb2`):

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb2   | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                    |    2 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | sistema.tb2.tb1_id      |    1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: É MySQL? SQL Server? Não se esquece de [edit] as tags da sua pergunta.

Comment: MySQL. Já atualizei, obrigado.

Comment: Só te interessam as linhas da `tb2` onde há correspondência de ID com a `tb1`? Nesse caso você poderia usar um `INNER JOIN` em vez do `LEFT`.

Comment: Preciso das linhas da `tb1`, mesmo que não existam linhas na `tb2`

Comment: @RaulBaldnerJunior como fica o explain de somente `SELECT COALESCE(tb2.numero_novo, tb1.numero_original) as numero
FROM
tb1
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id
WHERE 
tb1.numero_original = <PARAM>`

Comment: @gmsantos editei a pergunta para adicionar esta informação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Baldner

Verifique se isso lhe ajuda:

```
/* Adquirindo os registros da tb1 que possuem registros na tb2, ou seja, os 5% */
SELECT tb2.numero_novo AS numero
  FROM tb2
 INNER JOIN tb1 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
 WHERE tb2.numero_novo = <PARAM>
/* Realizando união com os registros da tb1 que NÃO possuem registros na tb2, ou seja, os 95% restantes */
 UNION
SELECT tb1.numero_original AS numero
  FROM tb1
 WHERE tb1.numero_original = <PARAM>
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tb2 WHERE tb2.id = tb1.id)
```

A minha ideia foi de trabalhar com os 5% que possuem registros na tb2 utilizando o INNER JOIN que é  mais rápido que LEFT JOIN.

Os outros 95% registros da tb1 que não possuem registros na tb2 basta utilizar o NOT EXISTS ao invez do LEFT JOIN.

A União teria como papel do OR melhorado.

Nos avise se isso melhorou ou piorou.

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! 
Infelizmente, não pretendia usar UNION pois preciso utilizar outros parâmetros de pesquisa na tb1. Eu precisaria duplicar os parâmetros nos 2 SELECTS ou então colocar este UNION como subquery e filtrar uma vez só depois (o que acho que seria muito ruim).

Comment: Eu não sei quais outros parâmetros você está precisando mas, dependendo do caso, vale a pena duplicar nas duas consultas. Por que você não tira a dúvida realizando um teste de performance ?